# convert php script into vba excel script

Tags: php, excel, vba

i tried to make my script from php to excel, and everything works fine, until the array does not add item, can someone help me please how to fill out array value in while loop? where is the issue in array ?

```
$diff = monthDiff('2020-01-01', '2021-02-10') + 1;
$offset = 5;
while($diff >= $offset) {
  $result[] = $diff - $offset;
  $offset += 3;
}
echo array_sum($result); // print 18
```

i tried in excel vba :

```
dt_diff = DateDiff("M", '2020-01-01', '2021-02-10') + 1
Dim result() as String
Dim offset As Integer
offset = 5
Do While dt_diff >= offset
  result() = dt_diff - offset
  offset = offset + 3
Loop
   
TestDates = WorksheetFunction.Sum(result) // print 18
```

thanks..

Comment: Unfortunately converting code from one language to another is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks, braX! But both are my own scripts, i share my code to someone if know where is the issue, did I fill out the array correctly in while loop or not, where is the mistake, I am not asking to convert the whole code since it's already done!

Comment: You need to declare how many elements will your array have (something like `Dim result(99) as String` will declare an array of 100 elements (minimun index by default is 0). Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-arrays

Comment: Yes, I did but it give error, the problem is how to fill out the array in loop, i did also Dim result() As  Variant to make it dynamic but the problem how to fill it in while loop?

Comment: Why not just summate in the loop and dispense with the array ? Are the payment due dates always the last day of the month ?